# Firefox plugin to view a site's mobile view on desktop

Tags: firefox, css

Every site has a mobile view and I think it's better than their desktop view because the former utilizes the screen space more efficiently. A mobile view only shows the most relevant content whereas the desktop view tries to show the sidebar, the ads, and such.

Every site has @media-queries in their CSS which determine whether you're a mobile user or a desktop user. For example

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {...
```

If you go to Style Editor (Shift+F7) and change that to something higher like 2000px it then thinks that anything lower than that is a mobile device and effectively shows the mobile view to desktop.

Is there a plugin that does this (alters the site's @media queries) automatically? I.e. goes through the site's CSS and manipulates the @media queries to do this automatically?

Comment: Does what? Modifying the `@media` CSS part – or pretending to be of the given resolution for viewing?

Comment: @Izzy Modifies the `@media` queries of the site's CSS files. Much like you manually can if you go to style editor (Shit+F7) and find all those media querries and manually change those max-width values

Comment: OK, I see. As you've discovered the internal editor for that already, maybe you could [edit] your question again and specify more precisely what you expect from it? I could think e.g. of a "simple drop-down with configurable entries", for quick-injecting with two clicks, or a slider, or …?

Comment: @Izzy The main thing is the ability to change the site's CSS files. The Style Editor was just an example. It can be achieved with Style Editor manually but I don't think a plugin would go that route, I imagine it would rather directly have access to the CSS files on which to do the manipulations automatically, like regex search and replace or something. How it does it, with a drop down, or two clicks aren't important, I think. Appreciating your help in phrasing my question better.

Comment: OK then, agreed that the *how* (drop-down/whatever) is secondary. I still feel some more details on what to change based on what (e.g. just the "max-width" value, and just for one fixed number, or iterating over a set using a pre-configured "pause", etc.) cannot hurt to make your "real wishes" clear, but I'll bother you no more with that :) Good hunting then!

Comment: It is not an exact answer to your question since it is not specifically related to CSS: But normally only the useragent-string decides over desktop- or mobile-view of a webpage. To switch this on the desktop Firefox I am using the "Mobile View Switcher" add-on (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mobile-view-switcher/). It uses the useragent of some iPhone by default but you can configure anything you want to. Then you only have to hit the button to enable or disable it.